# Rails: ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError FATAL: database "sale_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I been trying to deploy my app with Heroku, when I try to run the server with

rails server -b $IP -p $PORT

It keeps giving me an error that says 
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError
FATAL: database "sale_development" does not exist

Here is my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
 <<: *default
  database: sale_development


test:
  <<: *default
  database: sale_test


production:
 <<: *default
 database: sale_production
  username: sale
  password: <%= ENV['SALE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

What I don't understand is why it is saying "sale_development" does not exist
It should exist because sale is the name I named my app

Comment: After pushing the code to Heroku, did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ? You have to run that. And Heroku don't use `database.yml` from your code, so it does not matter.

Comment: what do you mean pushing? If I run heroku run rake db:migrate, it says no app specified

Comment: How are you deploying the app ? I supposed that you are deploying via git by pushing your code to Heroku's remote url. Regradless of deploying method, to solve the `no app specified` error, run that command from the directory of your app.

Comment: now when i run heroku run rake db:migrate, it seems to work but i still can't open my app

Comment: If you can't open the app then there must be some errors, check the logs by running `heroku logs` from your application directory.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to deploy? Is this your first time deploying the app?

When you run `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT` you are either binding to the wrong IP meaning the command is run locally, where you haven't created your dev db. Or you are successfully running rails server command with that IP, but you have failed to include the -e flag for environment so by default your app will be run with the development environment. In that case add flag `-e production` to your command.

On a side note, I am not sure why you are wanting to run the `rails server` command on heroku in the first place as it is not needed during the deploy process.

If the problem is that you have successfully deployed but you have no db run: `heroku run rake db:create` and subsequently `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Yes, this is my first time

Comment: @bockdavidson what about `heroku run rake db:create` and `heroku run rake db:migrate`? Remember to run `heroku run rake db:create` after your first deploy, and then migrate as those commands are not run automatically.  Again there is no necessity to run rails server on heroku, as long as there are no issues with your app rails server auto starts when you deploy; so i'm not sure why you are attempting to run rails server on heroku to begin with. Tail the logs and see what errors are occurring.